# AppWidgetManager getAppWidgetIds returning old Widget ids

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I'm trying to get a list of all ACTIVE instances of my widget. In the OnUpdate method of my AppWidgetProvider, I'm doing the following:

```
// Get all ids
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, this.getClass());
int[] lastWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
```

The problem is that if you add a widget to your homescreen and then delete it, getAppWidgetIds still returns a list containing among others the id of the widget you just deleted.

Is there a way to retrieve the ids of only the widgets that are active on the homescreen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into this as well. I'm guessing that getAppWidgetIds is simply programmed to always get all IDs ever associated with that widget provider.  To solve this, I had to save the Widget ID to my shared preferences by saving the id in the `onUpdate` method and deleting it in the `onDelete` method of my AppWidgetProvider.

```
public class MyProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) { 
        // Update your widget as normal

        // If the Id isn't already saved to your db/app preference, save it now
    }

    public void onDeleted (Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // Remove each id passed in through appWidgetIds 
        // "un-save" them from your db or app preferences
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to tell the appWidgetManager to check this issue and remove un-needed entries?

Comment: a slightly better way may be to save it in the Config Activity if you have one, since `onUpdate()` gets called many times.

Comment: Maybe the id is invalidated, which can be checked via `AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID`?